# What does it mean to access a data structure

Tags: data-structures

Pretty Basic Question I guess, but at this webpage:
https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

In the first table titled "Common Data Structure Operations", There is a column named Access

What does it mean to access a data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the chart, I believe what they are trying to imply access is to access an specific element (1st , 2nd or ith element) thats why hash table has N/A. you cant access elements by order in hash table.